# Is it possible to check for java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to check for a `NumberFormatException` for input string: `""`?

I tried to write my program so that if the user didn't put in any values an error message would come out instead of NumberFormatException:

```
if(pasientNavnFelt.getText() == "" || pasientNrFeIt.getText() == "")
{
  utskriftsområde.setText("ERROR, insert values");
}

if(pasientNavnFelt.getText() != "" || pasientNrFeIt.getText() != "")
{ 
  // rest of code here if the program had values in it
}
```

I also tried with null:

```
if(pasientNavnFelt.getText() == null || pasientNrFeIt.getText() == null)
{
  utskriftsområde.setText("ERROR, insert values");
}

if(pasientNavnFelt.getText() != null || pasientNrFeIt.getText() != null)
{ 
  // rest of code here if the program had values in it
}
```

I still get:

> `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

The program works fine if it has values.

Comment: Incorporate a try-catch block to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never compare Strings with `==`. `==` checks that the two objects are the same, and not that the two objects have the same characters. Use `equals()` to compare strings.

That said, to validate that a string is a valid Integer, you indeed need to catch the exception:

```
try {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    // s is a valid integer
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // s is not a valid integer
}
```

This is basic Java stuff. Read the [Java tutorial over exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if( pasientNavnFelt.isEmpty() || pasientNrFeIt.isEmpty()) {
   utskriftsområde.setText("ERROR, insert values");
}
else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Worth noting one of the OP's original issues was using `==` for String equality, rather than `.equals(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your second if condition is wrong.   You're trying to say, if there's a null, error, else do something.  You're saying if there's a null error, then if either of them is not null, do the rest.   The two character change is change the second "||" to a "&&".  But what you probably want is actually:

```
   if(pasientNavnFelt.getText() == null || pasientNrFeIt.getText() == null)
        {
            utskriftsområde.setText("ERROR, insert values");
        }
   else 
       { <rest of code here if the program had values in it>}
```